# String concatenation of hex strings in Python

Tags: python

Can anyone explain to me why the following snippet doesn't work? The resulting hex string will be only two characters long.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

s = 'Hello, World!'

hs = ''
for i in range(len(s)):
    c = s[i:1]
    hs += c.encode('hex')
print hs
```

Answer (score 2):

Because on each loop, you're trying to slice from `i` (which is increasing) to position `1` - which means after `i` > 1, you get empty strings...

It looks though, that you're doing:

```
from binascii import hexlify

s = 'Hello, World!'
print hexlify(s)
```

... the hard way...

Comment: And I know it can be done in a simpler way, I just wondered why this one wasn't working, and the reason was that I thought the second figure after the colon in the slice notation was a *length*, not an index.

Answer (score 2):

`c = s[i:1]` should be `c = s[i:i+1]` or `c[i]`

In python you can loop over the string itsellf, so no need of slicing in your example:

```
hs = ''
for c in s:
    hs += c.encode('hex')
```

or a one-liner using `str.join`, which is faster than concatenation:

```
hs = "".join([c.encode('hex') for c in s])
```

Comment: Yes, of course. I've been doing Perl until now, so I'm rather new at this. Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, I know that, I just used this as a silly example of something that I didn't think was working.

Comment: Oh, I love your one-liner, so pretty and elegant :)

Comment: @Ashiwini Chaudhary just one complement: `join()` also works with generator, not just lists, so: this is valid: `hs = "".join((c.encode('hex') for c in s))`

Comment: @Volatility the problem is that `.encode('hex')` won't work in Python 3.x, which is why I prefer to use `hexlify`

Comment: @PeterVaro I know that, but in case of `str.join` we should always use a list comprehension. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060653/list-comprehension-without-python/9061024#9061024

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary There is indeed no performance or memory reason to use a generator expression, but the difference is minuscule and using a generator expression saves a pair of brackets and reads more naturally, which is enough of a reason for me.